Attach Excel file to certain page/ location in word document using VBA
Can anyone help to share the VBA script on how to attach Excel file to certain page/ location in word document using VBA?
I successfully attached an excel file to words document but it attached in the first page.
it cannot be attached in certain location where I needed it to be attached.
I've tried using Find & Replace words, but it did not work.
Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(ReportFile)

With wDoc
    wDoc.Activate
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "ExcelFile"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = ""
    
    wDoc.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:= _
                                   "Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12", Filename:= _
                                   ReportFileS102, LinkToFile:= _
                                   False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:= _
                                   "C:\WINDOWS\Installer\{90160000-000F-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}\xlicons.exe" _
                                   , IconIndex:=1, IconLabel:=ReportFileNameS102 & ".xlsm"
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
End With


In the addOLE...  method call you are not specifying the range parameter that indicates where to place the shape. I think maybe you just need to put a comma at the end of the last line after the IconLabel:= parameter so that the .Application.Selection.EndOf is included as a parameter? You probably need to add Range:= as well

I have tried to put a comma at the end of the last line after the -> IconIndex:=1, IconLabel:=ReportFileNameS102 & ".xlsm", .Application.Selection.EndOf <- but it's error. would you mind to show me the example of range:= formula? thank you

Following OP's comment below I have revised the approach.
The following code works on my setup. It will require some modification to match OP's exact requirements but the structure as shown should be sufficient to get the Excel file to be inserted into the Word document at the position of the text "ExcelFile":
Option Explicit

Sub InsertExcelSheet()

    Dim allWords As Variant, word As Range

    '// Get a list of all the words in the doc. 
    '// Each entry in the list is a Range object
    Set allWords = ThisDocument.Words

    '// Iterate through all the words looking for "ExcelFile"
    Dim ix As Long
    For ix = 1 To allWords.Count
        Set word = allWords(ix)
        If word.Text = "ExcelFile" Then

            '// Remove the text
            word.Text = ""

            '// Insert the Excel file at the position of the word
            '// You will need to modify this to your particular
            '// file name and icon requirements per OP's original
            '// code.
            ThisDocument.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject _
                     ClassType:="Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12", _
                     FileName:="Test Excel Worksheet.xlsm", _
                     LinkToFile:=False, _
                     DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
                     Range:=word
                     
            '// Exit the loop
            Exit For
        End If
        
    Next ix
             
    
End Sub


Hi John, Thank you so much for elaborating the script. However I tried and it got a "Debug". Actually, with my previous script the macro is running well. but the excel file is attached in the top position in the words.
I need to attach the excel file in the certain position. I have tried to use, "Find & Replace text" script (as attached in my question above). however it doesn't work.
would you mind to give me another solution so that the excel file can be attached in the certain position? thank you.

Hi Michelle - I have changed my answer in the light of your comments, and tested it on my workstation. The code supplied seems to work fine, but as I say in the answer, you will need to modify some of it to match your exact requirements.

Hi John, thank you for the new script. However the words count script did not work.  Set allWords = wDoc.Words --- and --- allWords.Count

I guess you may already have fixed this. Yes, my example code is contained in the vb inside the document in which the link is to be inserted. I suggest you modify it so that you pass the reference to the document as a parameter to the Sub, and use that parameter instead of ThisDocument
